# Value is not valid with Seam and JFS

Tags: validation, jsf, seam

I had to create an arraylist named listaInformacaoMista and I put an object in it and after I put another arraylist, like the following code:

listaInformacaoMista.add(informacao);
listaInformacaoMista.addAll(informacoes);

But 'informacao' is an object that I created separately and 'informacoes' is a list that I got from data base using a method on service.
The trouble is: when I use a component  in my XHTML and select 'informacao' (that I created separately), an error happens with my application: "value is not valid".
Detail: I already use the Seam's converter  and I already override the methods equals and hashcode.

I'd like some help, please.

Comment: Can you place some of your codes here, specially the xhtml components. Since you are receiving "value is not valid" i'm guessing there is something wrong with the value you set in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the equals method on your object in the arraylist.